# What is/are Antonyms for Weltschmerz?

Tags: antonym

What is/are Antonyms for Weltschmerz? in German of course,

I looked up http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/weltschmerz but there were no German words amongst it's antonyms.

Comment: Mit sich und der Welt zufrieden sein.

Comment: Well, *feeling of anxiety* isn't the meaning either. *Weltschmerz* isn't anxiety, but deep desperation about being as such. So, the best antonym I can think of is *tranquility*, when your soul is at rest. In German *Seelenruhe*.

Comment: Seelenfrieden might be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit too broad, actually, but anyway, to complement Min-Soo's fabulous list:

> gute Laune

Then, also, I would accept a word like

> Weltzufriedenheit

although it is a neologism, but in a suitable environment (creative writing) you are free to create your own words.

Third, I think, when imagining a person in the state of *Weltschmerz*, then the opposite would be a person in the state of

> Euphorie

or in more everyday language a person in

> Feierstimmung, Feierlaune

or possibly a person in

> Jubelstimmung

Such a person would be perceived as being

> enthusiastisch

Answer (score 9):

[Lebensmut](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lebensmut), [Zuversicht](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zuversicht), [Frohmut](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Frohmut), [Frohsinn](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Frohsinn), [Le­bens­be­ja­hung](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lebensbejahung), [Eu­thy­mie](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Euthymie)

Comment: Euthymie... wow. Und ich dachte, das bezeichnet das Bestreben, durch Anwendung von Thymian Gutes zu bewirken, zum Beispiel in der Küche. –

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Geht natürlich auch, hieße dann aber wahrscheinlich eher Euthymianie, oder auch Euthymanie. ;-)